# VM inside host VM cannot see avx cpu flag

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server installed on a VM inside VirtualBox. This VM acts as my host for other VMs. I ran a Linux based image using qemu inside this host VM. The host VM has cpu flag avx but the image ran by qemu does not have the avx flag in its /proc/cpuinfo. I ran it with --cpu Haswell,+avx,enforce flags which according to /usr/share/libvirt/cpu_map.xml should have avx already.

Thank you for the help!